# Are there any MFPs with Scan-To-Folder for less than $1000?

Tags: server-message-block

The title pretty much asks the question: Every MFP with the ability to scan to a SMB share with an editable file name I'm finding is more than $1000. Do cheaper ones exist?

Comment: Although this will likely be closed *[per the FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq#dontask)*, as a sysadmin, I never expected to have to scope requirements for scanners, copiers, faxes[!] or MFPs. Regardless, we chose to lease the majority of our high-volume print/scan/fax equipment. The answer is *"Yes, maybe there are MFPs for < $1000, but they will be very limited in features and you will be frustrated having to configure/admin/use them"*. My only real/useful advice would be to contact local vendors and compare their offerings.

Comment: @jscott.. excellent answer, inline with my previous experience.

Comment: what's an MFP??

Comment: This is probably a shopping question; personally, I've had to deal with this; look at HP multifunction printers like the M2727nf (possibly just under $1000 depending on where you live) and investigated scan-to-folder under Linux: http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html

Comment: @Javier, Multi Function Printer.

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites because of their very limited lifespan. See [Q and A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a Dell 3150CN that supports scan-to-folder. That model is discontinued, but there are a number of under-$1000 Dell models now that work the same way.